With pi-gen, why do I get "Unable to locate package nginx"?
I'm trying to build a custom Raspberry Pi image using pi-gen. The image should have nothing but the bare minimum to run SSH, Ethernet and Nginx.
To achieve this, I'm using pi-gen with a custom stage that looks like this:
nginx-stage/
|- 00-install-nginx/
|  `- 00-packages
|- EXPORT_IMAGE
`- prerun.sh

prerun.sh:
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ ! -d "${ROOTFS_DIR}" ]; then
    copy_previous
fi

00-packages:
nginx

Then I run it on GitHub Actions with usimd/pi-gen-action@v1, setting:
stage-list: stage0 stage1 stage2 ./nginx-stage

But it fails to find nginx:
[17:22:01] Begin /home/runner/work/raspi-nginx/raspi-nginx/nginx-stage
[17:22:01] Begin /home/runner/work/raspi-nginx/raspi-nginx/nginx-stage/00-install-nginx
[17:22:01] Begin /home/runner/work/raspi-nginx/raspi-nginx/nginx-stage/00-install-nginx/00-packages
Warning: realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/proc: No such file or directory
Warning: realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/dev: No such file or directory
Warning: realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/dev/pts: No such file or directory
Warning: realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/sys: No such file or directory
Warning: realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/run: No such file or directory
Warning: realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/tmp: No such file or directory
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Warning: E: Unable to locate package nginx
[17:22:01] Build failed
Warning: real   18m53.087s
Warning: user   0m0.080s
Warning: sys    0m0.233s

Error: pi-gen build failed with exit code 100
realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/dev/pts: No such file or directory
realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/sys: No such file or directory
realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/run: No such file or directory
realpath: /pi-gen/work/zs-nginx/nginx-stage/rootfs/tmp: No such file or directory
E: Unable to locate package nginx

Somewhere I read that the package name is nginx-full but that didn't work either. Plus, on a running Raspberry Pi, apt install nginx works just fine.
Why is that?
